# fix div AND clip div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if this is possible but I have a container div which houses 2 other divs, one to the left and one to the right.

On scroll I would like the div on the right to become fixed, 30px from the top (25px on mobile)

I could achieve this myself with waypoints BUT I also need the div to be clipped at the bottom. I basically just need a vertical line that joins a horizontal line.

I have been at it for days - every time I switch the div to fixed, it overflows the main container. I tried using a clipping path but it did not work and got very confusing as the main content is already in a clipping path.

I tried using tables to get the 2 divs the same height but it meant I couldn't control them independently.

I tried waypoints so that the second div was fixed on scroll with an offset of 30px, but again I can't get it to clip.

This is the url - https://www.sheree-new.shereewalker.com/

NB the left box is red just to help identify the first div. The div I would like to trim in the black on one on it's right.

Here is a screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL8YI.jpg

The main html

```
<div class="section-size">
        <div class="large-yellow-container">
                <div class="heading-box">
                    <h2 class="large-h2"> <!-- Actual text -->
                    <?php
                    $value = get_field( "large_h2" );

                    if( $value ) {
                        echo $value;
                    } else {
                        echo 'empty';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="vertical-box">
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The CSS

```
.large-yellow-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative
}

.heading-box {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.vertical-box {
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
}



h2.large-h2  {
    font-size: 141px;
    line-height: 172px;
    font-family: 'Tiempos';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 90px 200px 90px 0;
}
```

I am already using jquery if that helps.